# Will select() return before next jiffy if waiting on a high resolution timerfd?

Tags: linux, time

If I have

- A kernel with CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS=y,
- A coarse CONFIG_HZ (say, 100)
- and a file descriptor from timerfd_create with a sub-jiffy
  expiration

Should a call to select() on this timer return before the next jiffy, as say, clock_nanosleep would?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the [`select()` timeout](http://git.kernel.org/linus/8ff3e8e85fa6) and the [`timerfd_create()` timer](http://git.kernel.org/linus/b215e2839928) are implemented with high-resolution timers on any recent kernel.